# How to pass result from angular 8 material dialog to other component?

Tags: angular, dialog

I have in Component1 a dialog Component2. When I have a result = true in Component2 I want to call a function in component1.

So, I have in `Component1` this code:

```
  searchbyenumber() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Component2, {
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.LoadTrainingSessionPartecipants();
      }
    });
  }
```

In Component2 I have this code:

```
  public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<Component2>

      confirmYes() {
        let Enrollment = new EnrollmentModel();
        Enrollment.PersonId = PersonId.toString();
        this.dataservice.SetEnrollment(Enrollment).then(
          result => {
            if (result) {
              console.log('result11', result)
            } else {
            }
          }
        );
      }
```

So when I get a result true from this function `confirmYes()` I want to execute `searchbyenumber()` function `this.LoadTrainingSessionPartecipants()` that I have in `Component1`

Please can you share with me any idea how to call it?

Answer (score 0):

You should inject `MatDialogRef` in your dialog component (Component2), then when you get the result and can close the dialog just call its method `close()` passing result as an argument; this will trigger `afterClosed` where you can access the data in Component1, that part of your code seems correct.

In Component2 you shoud do something like this:

```
 constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<Component2> // <-- INJECTION
             ... other injections
             ) { }

 confirmYes() {
    let Enrollment = new EnrollmentModel();
    Enrollment.PersonId = PersonId.toString();
    this.dataservice.SetEnrollment(Enrollment).then(
      result => {
        if (result) {
          console.log('result11', result);
          this.dialogRef.close(result); // <-- HERE
        } else {
        }
      }
    );
  }
```